# Render ProRes 422 AVPlayer into metal shader

Tags: swift, avfoundation, metal

I've been trying to render a ProRes 422 video into a metal shader but can't seem to get the conversion right between YpCbCr to RGB. I need the conversion to happen in a metal fragment shader but can't seem to make the output not purple.

I'm configuring the video output with the following:

```swift
videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString as String: kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8,
            kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey as NSString as String: true
])
```

And generating a metal texture as such:

```swift
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(nil, textureCache, pixelBuffer, nil, .bgrg422, width, height, 0, &cvTexture)
```

Really just torn on what the pixel formats want to be, and what the best way to feed this buffer into a metal shader is so that I can do the conversion to RGB.

Comment: There may be other answers (hopefully there are!), but when I've had to render YUV in metal, I've ended up pushing the planes to separate textures and then writing a custom shader to actually render them (converting to RGB within the shader).

Comment: @jnpdx that's what I'm hoping to do. I'm just not sure the steps to getting the pixel buffer to the shader - and what the shader code would be.